# Find the bisection of two 3D lines

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, sympy

I would like to calculate the bisection of two 3D lines which have an intersecting point. The lines are sympy lines defined by a point and a direction vector. How can I find the equation of the two lines which are the bisection of them?

Comment: @Stratubas the bisection is a line whose points are equidistant of two lines. The angles between the bisection and both lines are equal. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection#Angle_bisector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let lines are defined as `A + t * dA, B + s * dB` where `A, B` are base points and `dA, dB` are normalized direction vectors.

If it is guaranteed that lines have intersection, it could be found using dot product approach (adapted from skew line minimal distance algorithm):

```
u = A - B
b = dot(dA, dB)
if abs(b) == 1: # better check with some tolerance
   lines are parallel
d = dot(dA, u)
e = dot(dB, u)
t_intersect = (b * e - d) / (1 - b * b)
P = A + t_intersect * dA
```

Now about bisectors:

```
bis1 = P + v * normalized(dA + dB)
bis2 = P + v * normalized(dA - dB)
```

Quick check for 2D case

[image]

```
k = Sqrt(1/5) 
A = (3,1)     dA = (-k,2k)
B = (1,1)     dB = (k,2k)
u = (2,0)
b = -k^2+4k2 = 3k^2=3/5
d = -2k  e = 2k
t = (b * e - d) / (1 - b * b) = 
    (6/5*k+2*k) / (16/25) =  16/5*k * 25/16 = 5*k
Px = 3 - 5*k^2 = 2
Py = 1 + 10k^2 = 3
normalized(dA+dB=(0,4k)) =   (0,1)
normalized(dA-dB=(-2k,0)) = (-1,0)
```

Comment: What is "u"? In the second example it is predefined @MBo

Comment: And what is "v"?

Comment: `v` is just parameter for bisector parametric line equation, you don't need it

Comment: I have posted a python implementation of the algorithm but it is currently wrong. Check the geogebra link please.

Comment: You subtracted direction vectors to get `u` while **base points** are needed. In your case base point is the same, u = [0,0,0]. Here is no need in calculation of intersection point at all - you already know it.

Comment: Hmmm so what should I change? The intersection point between both lines can be calculated using sympy.

Comment: Just calculate  direction_ratio's. All other stuff is for the case of unknown intersection.

Comment: Still not right. The key is the sum and difference of the two direction ratios?

Comment: Yes, bisectors are sum and difference of the two direction ratios - but direction vectors **must be of the same length** - for example, normalized to unit length - and your current example shows different lengths

Answer (score 0):

Python implementation:

```py
from sympy.geometry import Line3D, Point3D, intersection


# Normalize direction vectors:
def normalize(vector: list):
    length = (vector[0]**2 + vector[1]**2 + vector[2]**2)**0.5
    vector = [i/length for i in vector]
    return vector

# Example points for creating two lines which intersect at A
A = Point3D(1, 1, 1)
B = Point3D(0, 2, 1)

l1 = Line3D(A, direction_ratio=[1, 0, 0])
l2 = Line3D(A, B)

d1 = normalize(l1.direction_ratio)
d2 = normalize(l2.direction_ratio)

p = intersection(l1, l2)[0]  # Point3D of intersection between the two lines

bis1 = Line3D(p, direction_ratio=[d1[i]+d2[i] for i in range(3)])
bis2 = Line3D(p, direction_ratio=[d1[i]-d2[i] for i in range(3)])
```